# Each layer of the eclipse package shows all paths

Tags: eclipse

My version of eclipse is 2022-03. I downloaded and installed spring tools4 from the  **Eclipse Marketplace** and created a boot project through **file** - > **New** - > **spring starter project**,I have set **Package Presentation** - > **Hierarchical**.

Although the eclipse package is layered, each layer shows all paths.

[uncropped screenshot Boot Project hierarchical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t9TH.png)

I test that the package of an ordinary **Java Project** is normal hierarchical.

[Java Project hierarchical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkOdG.png)

This is my .project file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>demo</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.validation.springbootbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Do you see this in a faceted project in an outdated Eclipse? If yes, upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .    eclipse  version：2022-03   .                                                                                            The project created by Spring Tools4.

Comment: A fresh installation? Please show an uncropped screenshot and the `.project` file.

Comment: I downloaded and installed spring tools4 from the Eclipse Marketplace. The spring tools4 version is 4.14.1 release and the eclipse version is eclipse-jee-2022-03 .Please see my question for uncropped screenshot and .project file.

Comment: That's a known bug that occurs in faceted projects (projects having the `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature` nature) that has already been fixed (wait for the next release or update to the current milestone of the next release): https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=579170